# Range copyFrom: The request is aborted

Tags: excel, typescript, office365, power-automate, office-scripts

```
function main(workbook: ExcelScript.Workbook) {
     let Source = workbook.getWorksheet("Sheet1");
     let Target = workbook.getWorksheet("Sheet2");
     Target.getProtection().unprotect("Password");
     let CopyRange = Target.getRange("C1");
     let LastRowVal = CopyRange.getValues() as number[][];
     let LastRow = LastRowVal[0][0];
     Target.getRange("B" + LastRow).copyFrom(Source.getRange("B3:J90"), ExcelScript.RangeCopyType.values, false, false);
     Target.getProtection().protect({}, "Password");
```

Sheet2.C1 is just a countA of B column +2 .

Script works manually, no error at all, in Excel 365 Desktop and Excel 365 Web.
it copies correctly and paste the data correctly.

However, when I use it on power automate it breaks.
Error from power Automate: "Range copyFrom: The request is aborted."

How can I troubleshoot the issue? or what could have cause the error?
Only protection on both sheet are the same password.

Comment: `unprotect("Passw0rd");` `protect({}, "Password");` -- Passwords are different. Is it a typo?

Comment: sorry nope just a typo on that part...  when i modified for this question made a typo.

Comment: I havetested running the script with Power Automate and did not run into any errors on my side. As a troubleshooting step, try temporarily unprotecting the target worksheet and commenting out the `protect/unprotect` lines of code. Then attempt to execute the script again through Power Automate.